# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Not Recognising Valid Value In Config File

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In .ebextension/myconfig.config I have the following:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: LoadBalancerHTTPSPort
    value: 443
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: SSLCertificateId
    value: arn:REDACTED
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: LoadBalancerHTTPPort
    value: OFF
```

When I push this to my EB environment, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Value is not one of the allowed values: [OFF, 80]
```

The problem is with `LoadBalancerHTTPPort`. If I set that to 80 instead of OFF, my app deploys no problem. Not really sure what gives.

Comment: For the benefit of others who come here looking for the answer: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=158875

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML passes ON/OFF as booleans. Solution was to wrap in quotes.

```
option_name: LoadBalancerHTTPPort
value: "OFF"
```